# Hibernate Mapping Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, struts

I have 2 Entity classes ParameterGroupBean and GroupLevelBean

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;


@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_ParameterGroups")
public class ParameterGroupBean {


@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int ParameterGroupId;
private String ParameterGroupName;  
private Boolean Status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="LevelId")
private GroupLevelBean level = new GroupLevelBean();

public GroupLevelBean getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(GroupLevelBean level) {
    this.level = level;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getParameterGroupId() {
    return ParameterGroupId;
}

public void setParameterGroupId(int parameterGroupId) {
    ParameterGroupId = parameterGroupId;
}

@Column(length=120) 
public String getParameterGroupName() {
    return ParameterGroupName;
}

public void setParameterGroupName(String parameterGroupName) {
    ParameterGroupName = parameterGroupName;
}

public Boolean getStatus() {
    return Status;
}

public void setStatus(Boolean Status) {
    this.Status = Status;
}
}
```

GroupLevelBean:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;


@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_GroupLevel")
public class GroupLevelBean {

private int LevelId;
private String LevelName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "level")
private Collection<ParameterGroupBean> parameterGroups = new ArrayList<ParameterGroupBean>();


public Collection<ParameterGroupBean> getParameterGroups() {
    return parameterGroups;
}

public void setParameterGroups(Collection<ParameterGroupBean> parameterGroups) {
    this.parameterGroups = parameterGroups;
}


@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getLevelId() {
    return LevelId;
}
public void setLevelId(int levelId) {
    LevelId = levelId;
}
@Column(length = 30)
public String getLevelName() {
    return LevelName;
}
public void setLevelName(String levelName) {
    LevelName = levelName;
}   
}
```

The relationship between GroupLevelBean and ParameterGroupBean is one to many.
I am getting an exception when i try to create a session object.

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.vrde.daems.bean.GroupLevelBean, at table: tbl_ParameterGroups, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(level)]

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are putting `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` java persistence annotations above:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int ParameterGroupId;
```

and in same time above:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public int getParameterGroupId() {
    return ParameterGroupId;
}
```

Its enough just to put annotations above `private int ParameterGroupId;`

Comment: Annotate the getters or annotate the fields, but not both.

Comment: @StevenBenitez Thats what I said. :)

Comment: Kind of, yeah. I prefer to annotate getters and I just wanted to drive home that either is acceptable. Your answer seemed to be favoring the fields. :)